# what will be the impact of a 2-bit error in a ciphertext block for decryption if AES is used in ECB, CBC and CTR mode?

Tags: aes, cbc, ctr, ecb, error-propagation

So I was reading about 1-bit error propagation for AES mode and how it propagates in various modes. I was wondering how error would propagate in ECB, CBC and CTR modes if it was a 2-bit or a 3-bit error on the ciphertext block when the receiver decrypts the ciphertext?

Comment: Can't a two bit error be treated as a pair of independent one-bit errors?  Couldn't you work it out yourself based on that?

Comment: I think basically either a block is fully affected or a single bit is affected when it comes to single bit errors. I'll leave the realization what then happens with two-bit errors in the blocks affected by single bit errors.